# Why psutil.cpu_count() shows 16 on my 8 core mac

Tags: python-3.x, psutil

Why `psutil.cpu_count()` show 16 on my 8 core mac. I am using *Python 3.7.6* and *psutil 5.7.2*

Comment: why downvote? it's a clear, concise and genuine question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s because it’s showing the logical cores (number of physical cores multiplied by the number of threads that can run on each core). 
If you want to find out the physical core only then use: `psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)`
Read the docs here: https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.cpu_count for details.